How to create 2GP package when using JWT Bearer Type External Credentials
I am trying to create a 2GP managed package that includes named credentials / external credentials.
The issue I'm having is related to the Authentication Flow Type of my external credential being 'JWT Bearer Flow'. A JWT bearer flow type credential requires a certificate be added in the 'Signing Certificate' field, however it is not possible to package a certificate.
According to the metadata coverage docs, packaging named and external credentials in 2GP package is supported (certificates are not).
The release notes (Spring 24) tell us we can package named / external credentials

Add named credential and external credential components to second-generation managed packages (managed 2GP) and unlocked packages for distribution across development, test, and production environments. Manage more of your named credential configurations in your preferred source control repository, and then share named credentials across all of your orgs or distribute them via AppExchange. Previously, the named credential component was supported in managed 2GP and unlocked packages but not the external credential component.

The guide for packaging named credentials makes no mention of issues with JWT Bearer FLows
The support docs I found related to this seem to suggest I can create the package without the cert, and install after.

External credentials that use the OAuth 2.0 authentication protocol with the JWT Bearer Flow variant reference a signing certificate created in the subscriber org. After you install the package, you must create a signing certificate in the subscriber org. Then, use the Connect API or UI to assign the signing certificate to the installed external credential.

This would be fine for my use case, but when I try to create the package (with the cert in an unpackaged folder) I get an error stating the cert is not found, and package creation fails. When in the package folder the error is the certificate entity is not supported (as expected) and again package creation fails.
The question is how to create a package including external credentials that require a certificate?

There was a long discussion about this in the partner forums when Salesforce decided to ban most uses of the session ID in app exchange listed managed packages. I recommend you read that. Honestly, we gave up our attempt to adopt named and external credentials and used a custom route of implementing JWT for ourselves. They are not designed with packages in mind, IMHO.
